# Error creating aliases for docker on linux

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I want to create an alias to make it easier for me to delete all the images and all the containers that exist on my machine. The following is the function I have:

```
alias docker='function rma(){if [[ $@ == "rmai" ]]; then docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q); elif [[ $@ == "rmac" ]]; then docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q); else; docker $@; fi };rma'
```

however when updating the environment variables of my bash I get the following:

```
bash: /home/alex/.bashrc: line 149: syntax error near unexpected token `{if'
bash: /home/alex/.bashrc: line 149: `function rma(){if [[ $@ == "rmai" ]]; then docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q); elif [[ $@ == "rmac" ]]; then docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q); else; docker $@; fi };rma'
```

In theory, when I put in my terminal rmac: delete all containers and rmai: delete all images, someone could tell me what I can do, greetings!

Comment: The curly braces must be separated from the function body by spaces or newlines.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/